# The savannah watering hole

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, wordplay, story

**Scene one**

> Early summer in an African savannah. Gazelles gather at a watering hole to drink. Everything is peaceful. Then all of a sudden, out of nowhere a group of hyenas charge in and start attacking the defenseless gazelles.
>
> > *Yakyakyakyak! Aaahahhahaah!*
>
> Bodies are everywhere. The surviving gazelles run away in terror. The hyenas start feasting on the fresh carcasses.
>
> With the group is a young lion named Swingba. He goes to address the leader of the group, an older hyena named Lolba.
>
> – *Nice hunt today, Lolba. Once again.*
>   – *Ahahahhaah! They didn't stand a chance!*
>   – *I know this is a great spot and all. Gazelles and zebras come far and wide to drink in this place. But listen. I know there are lions headed this way. We really don't want to be here when they show up.*
>   – *Give up our spot? Are you crazy? Forget about it! Yakyakyak*

**Scene two**

> Mid-summer at the same watering hole. After another successful raid, the hyenas are again enjoying their prey. Swingba comes up to Lolba again.
>
> – *Listen, man. I really think we should move on from this spot. Those lions will be here any day now.*
>   – *Yak! I will not hear another word of it. We've slaughtered everyone that comes near this spot. If those lions are stupid enough to show their face here, we'll butcher them for meat like everyone else. Ahahhahahahhaah! Get out of my sight.*
>
> Swingba realizes that reasoning with these guys is hopeless, and quietly leaves to search for better company.

**Scene three**

> Near the end of summer in the same place. A few hapless zebras approach the watering hole, unsuspecting. Suddenly, hyenas!
>
> > *Yakyakyak! Aahhahahahah!*
> >
> > *RROAAAAAARRRRGH!*
>
> Lions appear out of nowhere, atracking zebras and hyenas alike. The hyenas are cut down like flies. Poor Lolba cries for his mother as he hopelessly tries to outrun the lions. The lions finish the day with a nice warm meal of hyena meat.

What is the moral of this story?

Hint:

> The time of year is relevant.

Comment: Trust yourself?

Comment: Not your neighbors?

Comment: What you gain on the Swingbas you lose on the roundabouts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No doubt the moral of other stories you've heard before:

> Pride comes before the fall!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

> Listen to people ideas, and be open-minded.

for

> Lolba,

because,

> If he had actually listened, the pack wouldn't get eaten.

Or for

> Swingba

it's

> when you can't do something really helpful, do something helpful,

like he

> realized

Comment: Hmmm. That sounds a bit too metaphysical for a puzzle with the wordplay tag ...

Comment: oh. wordplay? I saw "what's the moral" and didn't see that. sorry.

Comment: No need to be sorry. (I think that you can tell the moral in a way that it is a pun on something well known, perhaps a proverb. But I don't know the answer, so I might well be wrong.)

Comment: Wordplay tag? Then I think the answer is "the moral"